# should have done vs should had done (sequence of tenses)

Tags: modal-verbs, should, sequence-of-tenses

imagine you want to use "should have done" in a subordinate clause when there's some past tense in the main clause.

e.g.: "He said I should have(had?) done it."

which one is correct? 
or should i use some other modal verb for this purpose?
thanks

Comment: Have you seen our 'sister' site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)? It's a great site for more fundamental English questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"should had done" is never correct.

Go with "should have done".

Answer (score -1):

*should had done

is **totally off** (* means incorrect).

In how many great writers' work have you found it? In how many grammars? Well?